# how to echo out variables from my mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, echo

here is what i have try so far

```
<?php

//Convert the email to variable

$Tnumber2 = "{$_SESSION['Tnumber2']}"; 


//  Connect to the database

$db = mysql_connect("$Sname","$Uname","$Pname") or die("Could not connect to the Database."); 
$select = mysql_select_db("$Dname") or die("Could not select the Database."); 


$sql="SELECT * FROM $Tname WHERE Tnumber2='".$Tnumber2."'"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>
```

and here is the codes i use to echo out the variables from my mysql database

```
<?php echo $rows['Tnumber2']; ?>
<?php echo $rows['Idate']; ?>
<?php echo $rows['Iaddress']; ?>
```

thanks any help will be appricated.

Comment: Seems like ok.Are you getting errors ?

Comment: What do you want to do? A lot of security-holes in that code, but what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @samitha not at all not even the value in my mysql database did come out

Comment: `$result=mysql_query($db,$sql)`

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, i want to be able to get all the values that i created and store in mysql out to show to the users page just like i create a user form and fill out all the forms so i want to able to show those entries to the user page

Comment: Look in the manual... http://se2.php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: @SableFoste it says error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/gadexpre/public_html/accounts/search/results.php on line 308

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `$Tname` WHERE Tnumber2='".$Tnumber2."'"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $rows['Tnumber2']; 
                echo $rows['Idate']; 
                echo $rows['Iaddress'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the line

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

to

```
$result=mysql_query($db,$sql)
```

But also, you haven't set the variable `$Tname`, or started a session with `session_start();`.  Plus, there are a bunch of security holes.

Comment: it says error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/gadexpre/public_html/accounts/search/results.php on line 308

Comment: Your $db line should be `$db = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)`... I assume that is your line 308.  Make sure you have all four arguments, and they are correct.  If you are on a local server, use "127.0.0.1" for your DB_HOST.

Comment: Is your MySQL server running?  Are you able to run a query through the command line (eg, `SHOW TABLES`), or through PHPMYADMIN?

Comment: through my PHPMYADMIN

Comment: @SableFoste: would you delete your comment above that advises the OP to use the `mysql` function? I think it is misleading. I agree it should be used in preference, but it is clear they are using the legacy library, and of course the two cannot be mixed.

Comment: @halfer, I assume you mean the `mysqli` comment above.  That was indeed a typo (I meant `mysql`), but the rest of the comment was relevant, and you can't edit after 5 minutes.  Hopefully, these comments will be good enough to document the typo.  Also, it is not clear that you can't mix libraries, I have done it in the past (only on a very temporary basis) without an issue.  I 100% agree that it is not a good idea though... ;)

Comment: @SableFoste: ha ha, yes, I seem to have made the opposite typo! I'll get me coat...